# ListView crashes after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I implemented an endless scroll ListView, it works quite fine but after a "couple" of scroll, lets say 10, application crashes with this error

```
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:194)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:195)
        at com.bellantoni.chetta.lieme.ProfileFragment.onScroll(ProfileFragment.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1755)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:6554)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3664)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4492)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7690)
```

this is the part of the code where the application crashes

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                         int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

        boolean loadMore = 
                firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

        if(loadMore) {
            this.adapter.setCount(this.adapter.getCount()+8);
            //NEXT LINE CRASHES
             this.adapter.addAll(this.rows);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The onScroll method is implemented in the fragment where the list is created and populated. the variable `rows` is a `List<>` of what I want to put in. And my Adapter is something like this

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItemProfile> {

private final Activity context;
private List<RowItemProfile> rows;
private int count = 8;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<RowItemProfile> rows ) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, rows);

    this.context = context;
    this.rows = rows;
}



public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);
    rowView.setPadding(0,10,0,10);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameList);
    txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgList);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    TextView idfacebook = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.facebookId);
    txtTitle.setText(this.rows.get(position).getNameSurname());
    imageView.setImageResource(this.rows.get(position).getIdImg());
    extratxt.setText(this.rows.get(position).getQuestion());

    idfacebook.setText(this.rows.get(position).getId());
    return rowView;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
}
```

I can't figure out why!

Comment: Can't see why someone down-voted this question without leaving a comment.  There is good provision of information in the question and it seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: just because a couple of line of code was not properly formatted! -.-"

Comment: or better, only one line of code was not formatted, just some more spaces!

Comment: ask to [Ajay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3498931/ajay-p-prajapati)

Comment: @Bella : Showing the code for the `getView(...)` method may help. Are you using `Bitmaps` in your list items?

Comment: @Squonk I edited with the code that you asked. No I do not use bitmap but I set a drawable resource instead

Comment: i haven't voted down this question, i just edited to make it properly formatted code as stack overflow suggests.

Comment: @Bella : You're not reusing the `View` passed in to `getView(...)` as the second parameter. The usual way to implement `getView` is to check if that `View` is null or not - if it *IS* null then reuse it otherwise inflate a new `View` to use.

Comment: @Squonk so when the method `this.adapter.addAll(myList);` the `getView` is invocated right? Hence in the in the `getView()` first I check if it is null, and if not what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I post it here,  maybe it will be useful for someone else. 
I do not why but the combination of these 2 things solved mywind problem:

1. Use of the Picasso library to download the image
2. Adding just one element at a time instead of a list of 8 elements all at the same time(I think the most important one).

Answer (score 1):

the objects are creating in getview for each item, which may cause exception. For 100% efficient scrolling and objects creation replace your getview method with below code.

first in initialize the `LayoutInflater` object in constructor of `CustomListAdapter` 
and also create a new inner class `ViewHolder` in `CustomListAdapter`

ViewHolder

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle,idfacebook,extratxt  ;
    ImageView imageView ;
}
```

replace your getview() method with

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row, which is expensive!
    ViewHolder holder;

    /* 
     * If convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, no inflation required!
     * We only inflate a new View when the convertView is null.
     */
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pocket, null);

        // Create a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameList);
        holder.extratxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        holder.idfacebook = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebookId);
        holder. imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgList);

        // The tag can be any Object, this just happens to be the ViewHolder
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Bind that data efficiently!

    holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(this.rows.get(position).getNameSurname());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(this.rows.get(position).getIdImg());
    holder.extratxt.setText(this.rows.get(position).getQuestion());

    holder.idfacebook.setText(this.rows.get(position).getId());

    return convertView;
}
```

if it does not solve your problem then you are using image in listview with large size, then you need to resize the image size. hope it help.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I tried also with small images

Comment: Try redefining the getItem and getItemId methods from you adapter.
I'm just thinking out loud, but desperate times call for desperate measures.

Comment: If you want you can give me git access to you project so I can see what is going on. Once I locate the problem I will post the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these methods before the `getView()` method

```
public int getCount() {
    // return the length or size of your List rows
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```